# Electric Field due to Gauss' Law is different from Electric Field from integration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I was working on a problem that involves the electric field inside a cylinder, the derived equation is different when derived by integration and by Gauss' Law.
[image: Gaussian Cylinder]
Can anyone spot the error in my logic?

$$E =\frac{k dq}{r^2}\\\\
dq= \lambda r d\Theta \\\\
E =\frac{k\lambda}{r}\int_{0}^{2\pi }d\Theta\\\\
E= \frac{k\lambda2\pi}{r}\\\\
\lambda = \rho drdL\\\\
E=\frac{k2\pi \rho drdL}{r}\\\\
E = \frac{k \rho 2\pi}{r}\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{L}dLdr\\\\
E = \frac{\rho L}{2 \epsilon 0}
$$
I used r since that is the distance from the center of the cylinder to the surface.

Whereas, with Gauss' Law
$$
E = \frac{Q}{A\epsilon 0}\\\\
E = \frac{\rho(\pi r^2L)}{(2\pi r L) \epsilon0}\\\\
E = \frac{\rho r}{2 \epsilon 0}
$$

We see that the expressions are not equal. Where is the error in my Logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt should involve the addition of electric field vectors from each little bit of the source to point where you are evaluating the field. You can’t just add magnitudes… the electric field vectors at a point contributed from each bit of the source are not parallel.

Presumably your cylindrical source is infinite (since you implicitly used that in your Gauss Law calculation). So you can’t just use a finite section of the infinite cylinder.